# Is it possible to programmatically select a item in a <li *ngFor> list?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following list to be showed:

```
<li *ngFor="let player of players" [class.selected]="player === selectedPlayer" (click)="onSelect(player)">
    <a>
        <span class="badge">{{player.victories}}</span>
        <span class="badge2">{{player.matches}}</span>
        {{player.name}}
    </a>
</li>
```

I pass the *selectedPlayer* to a desendant component using a symple function:

```
onSelect(player: Player): void {
   this.selectedPlayer = player;
}
```

So the selected item is used to detail the player in another component.

The problem is: if I refresh the list the previously *selectedPlayer* will be lost, but I want to stay selected.

Comment: you have to save it, just add a flag in each row and according to change, you update you list, so if it's refresh, you can continue to have the selected items

Comment: Initially selectedPlayer is empty, and when  [class.selected]="player === selectedPlayer" tries to do this, it finds selectedPlayer to be empty. Hence, its false, and its not highlighting.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by refresh the list? Do you reload the page?

Comment: Its possible to add players to the list, and when thats done the list is refreshed (downloaded again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to "reselect" the correspondent *selectedPlayer* on the new list. Ts, html or Angular does the rest here (enlighten me if I'm wrong), in a way that I don't need to access the list and programmatically set the *new* selected.

For that I've made the following function:

```
private reSelectPlayer() {
  for (let p of this.players) {
    if (this.haveSelected) {
      if (p.id === this.selectedPlayer.id) {
        this.selectedPlayer = p;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which I call on the refresh function:

```
private refreshPlayersList() {
  this.playerService.getPlayerList().subscribe(
    players => {
      this.players = players
      this.reSelectPlayer();
  });
}
```

Notice that *haveSelected* is initialized with a false value and is setted to true when the user select an item on the list.

Comment: :) You can accept your own answer if you feel it's the best one.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it's normal to add the behavior you want, you can add a flag.

Add a flag to the object. For this case, I will create a new object:

```
class pObject{
    Player player;
    isSelected boolean:= false;
}
```

Modified the selected function:

```
onSelect(obj: pObject){
    this.pObject = obj;
    this.isSelected = ! this.isSelected ;
}
```

Update the display:

```
enter code here
...
```

Comment: The problem is not knowing which was the selected item. Is to reselect it without needing to click on the item in the list.